# Cannot POST api/signup

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning MEAN stack, I made one signup api and while testing it using POSTMAN I'm getting these weird error as cannot POST api/signup.

Below is image of error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6SO0.png)

My server.js file :

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var app=express();

mongoose.connect(config.database,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Coonnected to database");
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express);
app.use('api',api);


app.get('/home',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("Listening on port 3000");
    }
});
```

user.js file contains:

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var bcrypt=require('bcrypt-node'); 

var UserSchema=new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.pre('save',function(next){
    var user=this;
    if(!user.unModified('password')) return next();
    bcrypt.hash(user.password,null,null,function(err,hash){
        if(err) return next(err);
        user.password=hash;
        next();
    });

});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword=function(password){
    var user =this;
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
}

module.exports=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

api.js file :

```
var User=require('../models/user');
var config=require('../../config');

var secretKey=config.secretKey;


module.exports=function(app,express){

    var api=express.Router();

    api.post('/signup',function(req,res){

        var user=new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password

        });


        user.save(function(err){

            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            else
                res.json({ message:'User has been created'});   
        });

    });

    return api;
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Your client posts the request to the endpoint /api/signup but on the server you have the route /signup. Fix either or and then try again

Comment: Did you try `app.use('/api',api);` instead of `app.use('api',api);` ?

Comment: Also, please do not post images of text. Instead, post the relevant text in the question so that the text is more accessible and searchable and also in case the image link dies at some point.

Comment: @mscdex : that works for me..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`app.use('/api',api);`

instead

```
app.use('api',api);
```

For more on [`express routing`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the user.js you have a typo

```
if(!user.unModified('password')) return next();
```

this should be changed to

```
if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();
```